# Editar/alterar conteúdo da resposta

Tags: debate

Sei que este assunto é repetido, mas não quero falar no genérico quero esclarecer uma edição que aconteceu hoje mesmo comigo.

A edição em questão foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

"Olha este código a ver se funcionba:"
Sei que "funcionba" está mal escrito, agradeço por ter corrigido, mas não era só corrigir o que está errado?
Porque alterar a estrutura da frase? É correto?
Fico com a dúvida se a minha frase estava mal construída ou se quem a editou não gostou e decidiu por a maneira dele?

Atenção que não tenho nada contra, mas a frase agora não está um pouco pt/br, quando eu sou português e escrevo português(ou pelo menos tento)

Gostava que alguém me clarificasse se o que aconteceu está correto?

Qualquer esclarecimento fico agradecido

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considero a edição incorreta.

A estrutura pode parecer um pouco confusa para pt_br, mas com um pouco de bom senso é completamente entendível. Talvez quem editou não saiba que nem só de pt_br é feita a comunidade e resolveu "melhorar o entendimento", sem saber que existem outras nacionalidades que também participam da comunidade.

Isso pode ser considerado um erro comum para iniciantes e quanto a isso eu não vejo problemas, entretanto exatamente por esse motivo que temos as pessoas que analisam as sugestões de edição, e eu diria que essas pessoas devem prestar mais atenção e não terem medo de rejeitar as edições caso haja um bom motivo para tal.

Comment: Talvez não faça muito sentido... Dialetos existem, mas não sei se isso existe na norma culta, principalmente após o acordo ortográfico. O que acham de todos tentarem, pelo menos, escrever de acordo com o acordo (:D) ortográfico?

Comment: @Patrick não sei o que o acordo diz exatamente, apenas sei que saiu o "c" não pronunciado como por exemplo "incorreCto", quanto a isso ok corrigir, mas não foi o caso. Imagina se todo mundo resolve sair por aí alterando frases de voz passiva para ativa ou vice-versa, e coisas do tipo, não faz sentido. Temos que corrigir apenas o que precisa ser corrigido e respeitar a forma como o autor resolveu escrever a frase. Não existe apenas uma maneira correta de se escrever, e sim várias.

Answer (score 5):

Você é o autor da resposta e se você não gostou do que foi editado, é livre para reverter quando quiser.

Estritamente falando, uma correção seria trocar o *"ver"* por *"vê"* e o *"funcionba"* por *"funciona"*, apenas. *"Olha este código a vê se funciona"*. Mas quem editou achou que a frase poderia ficar melhor se fosse escrita de outra forma. E não há nenhum problema com isso, **desde que o sentido original da frase não mude**, e não acho que mudou. É bem comum que perguntas inteiras sejam reescritas quando alguém conclui que seu texto original estava ruim (muito ruim).

Quanto a essa edição em particular, não há nada de errado nela. Mas ela é desnecessária e não resolve tudo o que deveria. Outros pontos a melhorar seria remover o "boas" (já que não tem utilidade para responder a pergunta) e ajustar a formatação do bloco de código, que parece começar com 8 espaços em vez de 4. Seria passível de rejeição por não ter resolvido esses outros detalhes, mas reitero que não é incorreta no que faz.

Comment: Acho que o correto é "Olha este código a ver se funciona", e não da forma que você escreveu.

Comment: Ahh, interpretando o "a" como "com o intuito de" a frase faz sentido. Me é bem estranho escrever assim (tanto que nem entendi), mas se isso é comum em pt_pt, não devia ter sido mudado mesmo (afinal deve ter muita coisa em br estranha a eles também).